# how to use nested select query in codeigniter to get different result by each query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
`
$poplrRec = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".ADD_RECIPE." ORDER BY POPULARITY DESC LIMIT 4");
while($poplrRec1=mysql_fetch_array($poplrRec))
{
    $likecount=mysql_query("SELECT RECIPE_ID, COUNT(RECIPE_ID) FROM ".RECIPE_LIKE." WHERE RECIPE_ID=".$poplrRec1['RECIPE_ID']);
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($likecount))
    {
        $cmnt=mysql_query("SELECT RECIPE_ID, COUNT(RECIPE_ID) FROM ".RECIPE_CMMNT." WHERE RECIPE_ID=".$poplrRec1['RECIPE_ID']." AND TYPE=0");
        while($c=mysql_fetch_array($cmnt))
        {

 }} } `
```

hi here i use core php while loop and MySQL query so i have to use these type of query in MVC structure of codeigniter. And like here i want result of every query separate to use in mvc structure.
each query provide some data that need to use in somewhere in that relevant .
plz suggest me how can i implement these type of php query in codeigniter or mvc structure .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write query following format

```
$query = $this->db->get('vehicles_types');
            $result = $query->result_array();

            // loop through the types e.g. the parents
            foreach( $result as $key => $row )
            {

                // add the "examples" e.g. the children to the result array
                $query = $this->db->get_where('vehicles',array('type'=>$row['id']));
                $row['examples'] = $query->result_array();
                $result[$key] = $row;

            }

            return $result;
```

Comment: can we use separate results by all instead queries by these format..and how i fetch and by which variable.

Comment: thanks for helping me its really amazing answer and technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result=$this->db->query("select * from tableName");
 foreach($result->result() as $row){
  // $row has the associative array 

// you can again query the database with  $this->db->query
}
```